# Sensu Dashboard events contain stale events

Tags: sensu, uchiwa

I am trying to clear all the stale old renamed clients from my `uchiwa` dashboard. I am unable to clear them.

Basically I renamed the clients with a new name, but the old clients keep showing up on the dashboard.

I restarted `sensu-server`, `uchiwa` dashboard, and `redis-server`. Still I keep seeing the stale entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to get into `redis-cli` prompt, and run `flushall`. This cleared all the old events. Ideally redis-server restart should have cleared it. Well, now its all neat.

I also restarted rabbitmq-server.

Answer (score 1):

I saw you found A solution but maybe not the one and only.

So what’s happening is that, the clients will not automatically deregister which is an intended behaviour since otherwise you’d not get any sort of “keep alive’ alerts.

Moreover you might at some point just be willing to check if a check has not be running for a while, like we do but those alerts will hang around for example also if you just tested a check and never executed it again.

You can thus just go to the corresponding client you have an issue with on uchiwa and delete it from there.
You can perform the same action with a curl request against the sensu-api.

The advantage over hitting `flushall` is that you will only delete the client(s) you want to delete whereas `flushall` will also remove all your stashes which might be very annoying at a larger scale.

Answer (score 0):

In Uchiwa, under clients, you can select a client and delete it. The client will then disapear.